# Question of Cayley graphs of certain group

Tags: abstract-algebra, cayley-graphs

I want to draw the Cayley graph of $S_4$ with respect the rotations of the cube 90º with respect the y axis (is the one pointing up and I will call it $g_1$) and with respect the x axis (the one pointing right and I will call it $g_2$). If we call $G=<g_1,g_2>$ then this is the group of symmetries which turns out to be $S_4$.

Then my question this time is, How can I draw this graph?, I am stuck and I do not know how to begin, I know it has to have 24 nodes, but how to proceed in this?, **Thanks for your help in advance** :)

Comment: See [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cayley_graph_of_S4).

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, but which is the one that I have to choose ?